# Change the view of TabHost + Format buttons like a real keypad || Android

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-tabhost

Alright.. To start off, I'm new with Eclipse, new with Android Development, Java..

I have to make a VoIP Application, I set up some tabs (Yes the text is messed up) :

[image: Like this:]

And here's my XML Code.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<TabHost
    android:id="@+id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </TabWidget>

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/Recents"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:text="Recents">



            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/Keypad"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:text="Keypad" >

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bNumber1"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="1" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bNumber2"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="2" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bNumber3"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="3" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bNumber4"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="4" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bNumber5"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="5" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bNumber6"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="6" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bNumber7"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="7" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bNumber8"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="8" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bNumber9"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="9" />
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bNumber0"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="0" />


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bCall"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="Call" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bSMS"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="SMS" />
                 <Button
                    android:id="@+id/bClear"
                    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="C" />

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/etNumberField"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:ems="10"
                    >
                </TextView>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/Sms"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:text="SMS">
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/Ratings"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:text="Ratings">
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:id="@+id/Account"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" 
                android:text="Account">
            </LinearLayout>

        </FrameLayout>

         </LinearLayout>

          </TabHost>

        </LinearLayout>
```

Now, My problem is that I'll have to position all the "Number"-Buttons (1,2,3,4 etc..) and make them look like a real key-pad.

My problem is, I can't really "See" on the graphical layout how it's getting positioned.

I Can't code the buttons out of memory either, since I'm still new to it.
Is there anyone that could help me with the code, formatting them to a key-pad like format?

Or even give me a solution on how I could SEE the positioning as I'm coding it?

Thanks in Advance,

Paramone!

Comment: If you want to design an Android UI you are going to have to do your homework.  Read about TableLayout -- it makes it "easy" to produce a rectangular grid of buttons.   http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html

Comment: Also google "android layout tutorial".  You'll find lots of interesting and helpful links.

Comment: @DaleWilson Altho It wasn't completely what I asked for, It does help me. Will do!

Comment: gridview with columns having buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, After some research I've figured it out.

If anyone was wondering how to change the Tab-View as they're coding, and be able to see how it looks like..-

Simply create An .XML file, and design it as you want the tab to look like. 
Before this solution, I had to Edit my tab-views looking at this:

[image]

Later, you need to put in `<include layout="@layout/recents" />`  ("recents" is the .XML Layouts name.) in your Linear layout.

Mine looks like this:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/Keypad"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:text="Keypad"> 

       <include layout="@layout/keypad" /> 
                               //"keypad" is the name of the .xml file.
</LinearLayout>
```

---

And That's how you "Change" the view.

Also, Since I'm new to Android Developing, I wanted to know how I could format my so they'd look like a legit Key-pad.

Thanks to the include code, I could actually SEE the tab as I was coding and designing it.

Screenshots:

[image: End Result]

[image: End Result Alternative]

**What I did:**

**- Put all the buttons in Sets of 3.**

So 1 LinearLayout would cover Buttons 1, 2 and 3.

The other one would cover 4,5 and 6 (And so forth)

**- Put Weights on the LinearLayouts**

This helped me "Push" them to the bottom.

I know that it's probably not the correct or safest way to do it, but as long as it works, I'm happy with it.

The XML Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:paddingTop="10dp" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/etNumberField"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:ellipsize="end"
            android:ems="100"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:textSize="23dp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bContact"
            style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Contact" />
    </LinearLayout>

          <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:padding="1dp">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bNumber1"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="1"
                        android:padding="10dp" />

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bNumber2"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="2" 
                        android:padding="10dp"/>

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bNumber3"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="3"
                        android:padding="10dp"  />
        </LinearLayout>

         <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:padding="1dp">
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bNumber4"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="4" />
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bNumber5"
                       android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="5" />
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bNumber6"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="6" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:padding="1dp">

                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bNumber7"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="7" />
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bNumber8"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="8" />
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bNumber9"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="9" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:padding="1dp">
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bNumberStar"

                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="*" />
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bNumber0"

                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:text="0" />
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bNumberHash"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="#" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"

                android:padding="1dp">

    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bSMS"

                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="SMS" />
                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bCall"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Call"
                        android:textColor="#00FF00"               
                    />



                    <Button
                        android:id="@+id/bClear"
                        android:layout_weight="1"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="C"
                         />
                    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

If you have any questions regarding this solution, or how I could possibly help you, feel free to post a comment below!